# Objects not Colliding

Tags: xna, c#, 3d, collision-detection, debugging

I have been having a problem doing 3D collision detection in a game I have been trying to make for several weeks now. What I am trying to do is prevent a PlayerModel object from colliding with Obstacle(cube) objects. The code I have right now works perfectly fine but it only works correctly with the first Obstacle in the list of Obstacle objects I have. I have tried using a foreach and for statement to try and go through each object in the list but neither method worked. Also putting breaks and continue statements did not work either. The first code block that I want to post is the code in the player model object that checks for the collision.

I decided to leave in the comments I had from when I was debugging the code. Also this code block is all happening in the PlayerModel class.

```
//update future bounding sphere based on input
        this.futureBoundingSphere = new BoundingSphere(this.futurePosition.Translation, 10.5f);

        //collision checking last
        //What i think is going on - At first only one cube was being checked, so i just break out of the statement if we hit soemthing.,
        //i think that was the only way i could get the collision to get checked on multiple objects.
        //Also, i must take note of the bounding spehers, It is likely that the spacemans collision sphere is being drawn waaaay to large, suggest scaling spacemodel to test
        foreach (BasicModel obstacleModel in game.obstacles.models)
        {

            if (this.wholeCollidesWith(futureBoundingSphere, obstacleModel, obstacleModel.GetWorld()))
            {
                //note - First object in the list does second statement, last object does first statement
                game.aColor = Color.AliceBlue;
                futurePosition.Translation = this.world.Translation;
                //break; ////- adding in break will cause all but the first object to do the first statement
            }
            else
            {
                game.aColor = Color.Orange;
                this.world.Translation = futurePosition.Translation;
            }
        }

       //update actual bounding sphere last
        this.myBoundingSphere = new BoundingSphere(this.GetWorld().Translation, 10f);
```

The second code block I have is the wholeCollidesWith method that I use to check collision between single objects. Please keep in mind that I am not currently using the otherWorld parameter, I had used it once before but stopped using it because I am updating each object's bounding sphere whenever its update method is called.

```
//Whole model collision, not checking individual meshes
    public bool wholeCollidesWith(BoundingSphere futureBoundingSphere, BasicModel otherModel, Matrix otherWorld)
    {
        //Check if one object collides with another
        if(futureBoundingSphere.Intersects(
            otherModel.myBoundingSphere))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am not sure what is going on but I am hoping that it is a simple syntax error that I am overlooking with my foreach loop. In any case I hope there will be someone who might be able to find the error that I could not find, please request for any more code/information if needed.

Comment: I think debugging your code is too localized a question for the site. Check out the [FAQ] to learn what types of questions to ask here, and find some sites that are more open to discussion based questions like this one. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, I guess I assumed that it would be ok, I won't post any specific questions again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the `world.Translation` before you have a chance to check for collisions with the rest of the objects.

In the case where the first object is not colliding you set the `world.Translation` to be the `futurePosition.Translation`, then no matter what happens after that you are stuck with the `futurePosition.Translation` because you are essentially saying `futurePosition.Translation = futurePosition.Translation` (`this.world.Translation`) in the first part of the if statement.

Just set a `flag _collisionHappened` to `false` before entering the loop, then set it to `true` if you hit something. At the end of the loop check the flag and only update the translate if there was no collision.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I didn't realize you could hightlight code elements inline like that. Definitely makes it more readable.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked finally. I did not think that updating the world translation inside of the loop would affect the rest of the collision checking for the rest of the objects. Thanks again.